# Making Responsive menu more User Friendly

Tags: html, css

I have a mega menu which is working fine for me in responsive mode but I want to make it more user friendly when it is responsive because it takes a lot of space when it drops down.

Here is the code I am using:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Brands</a>
            <div>
                <div class="nav-column">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php?brands=1">Siemens</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?brands=2">KSB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?brands=3">Dadex</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?brands=4">Hyundai</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Products</a>
            <div>
                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Automation</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php?stypes=1">Logo!</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?stypes=2">Simatic-S7-200</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?stypes=3">Simatic-S7-400</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?stypes=4">Simatic-S7-1200</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?stypes=5">HMI</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Pumps</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php?products=7">Etanorm</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?products=8">KWP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?products=9">ZORO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?products=10">DWT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset */
.nav, .nav a, .nav ul, .nav li, .nav div, .nav form, .nav input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li {
    list-style: none;
}
/* Menu Container */
#menu-wrapper {
    border: 0 solid #000;
    width: 870px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 380px;
}
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 500;
    border: 0;
}
/* Menu List */
.nav > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
/* Menu Links */
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 510;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 54px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #434343;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#afafaf), to(#d8d8d8));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    border-left: 1px dotted #c8c8c8;
    border-right: 1px dotted #c8c8c8;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.nav > li:hover > a {
    background: #c8c8c8;
}
.nav > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-left: none;
}
/* Search Form */
.nav > li.nav-search > form {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    height: 54px;
    z-index: 510;
    border-left: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #434343;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#afafaf), to(#d8d8d8));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    transition: all .3s ease 1s;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus {
    color: #434343;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus, .nav > li.nav-search:hover input[type="text"] {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 0 solid #000;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    transition: all .3s ease .1s;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #d8d8d8 url(../images/header/search1.png) no-repeat center center;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
}
/* Menu Dropdown */
.nav > li > div {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#afafaf), to(#d8d8d8));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #afafaf, #d8d8d8);
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}
.nav > li:hover > div {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}
/* Menu Content Styles */
.nav .nav-column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    border-right: 1px dotted #c8c8c8;
}
.nav .nav-column h3 {
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #372f2b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav .nav-column li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #888888;
}
.nav .nav-column li a:hover {
    color: #666666;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #menu-wrapper {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .nav {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        cursor: default;
        border: 0 solid #000;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    .nav>li {
        background: #efefef;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    .nav >li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    .nav >li:hover > div {
        display: block;
        z-index: 999;
        position: static;
    }
    .nav .nav-column {
        float: none;
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is when a user clicks on the products `<li>`, all of the `<h3>` under the products `<li>` gets displayed only the `<h3>` gets displayed all of them. Then when a user clicks on an `<h3>` tag, only its corresponding `ul` gets displayed.

Here is a fiddle showing what I have tried so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/yH39r/4/

Comment: Can you please make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Mave http://jsfiddle.net/yH39r/ here is it the fiddle resize the result box until u get it responsive

Comment: @taposoka1 the mark-up in your fiddle is invalid. You're missing a closing `div` tag.

Comment: @Mave Check it now http://jsfiddle.net/yH39r/3/

Comment: @MarmiK the original fiddle that was created is missing a closing div. Paste it into an editor of your choice, but it is missing. In the latest version of the fiddle I have fixed it but check the first version here and you will see the missing tag http://jsfiddle.net/yH39r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have creates a simple jQuery code that will solve your issue..

Script:

```
 $('#menu-wrapper div.nav-column h3').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').css("display","none");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').css("display","");
    }
 );
```

Here is the working [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/yH39r/7/)

**Update: **

Updated answer with the different requirement..

Please check the Updated [`fiddle2`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/yH39r/10/)

This is with Pure CSS only,

I have just modified the original hierarchy a bit. 
(Converted `h3` in class and replaced tag with `div class="h3"`)

That did it!

**Update: **

Removal of Responsiveness..

Check this [`fiddle3`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/yH39r/11/) which doesn't change if the screen size is less-than 480px

Comment: Thanx for the Effort but what I really want is when someone hovers on the producsts all of the <h3> gets displayed at once and after that the desired <h3> <ul> gets expand when the user hover on it.

Comment: An excerpt from my Question which will better help u " What I want to achieve is when a user clicks on the products <li>, all of the <h3> under the products <li> gets displayed only the <h3> gets displayed all of them. Then when a user clicks on an <h3> tag, only its corresponding ul gets displayed."

Comment: Yep it works but just in the responsive mode when the screen shrinks less than 480px in desktop mode i dont want that thing :) how to get rid of that

Comment: Make the result panel large and u will get to know whats the issue

Comment: I have updated fiddle3 now this is my final update :D am not going to help further now

Comment: now thats ok will drive me certainly to my Desire! :)

Comment: happy that its final :D